# Can't delete a directory in Mac

Tags: macos, permissions, file-permissions

We have a bundle App.component and inside it we have a 'Contents' directory with the following permissions:

```
 drwxrwxrwx  4 root  wheel  136 Mar 18 15:05 Contents
```

When I try to delete this directory using

```
rm -rf Contents
```

It fails with the reason

```
rm: Contents//MacOS/APP: Permission denied
rm: Contents//MacOS: Directory not empty
rm: Contents//Resources/App.rsrc: Permission denied
rm: Contents//Resources: Directory not empty
rm: Contents/: Permission denied
```

lsof shows that there are no processes that are using this bundle 
and running stat Contents/Resources/App.rsrc outputs:

```
234881026 3691189 -rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel 0 733 "Mar 18 16:10:13 2012" "Mar  8 17:00:18 2012" "Mar 18 15:04:39 2012" "Mar  8 17:00:18 2012" 4096 8 0 Contents/Resources/App.rsrc
```

We do have permissions to delete the 'Contents' directory so why does it still fails?

Edit: If I move the bundle from /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Component to ~/tmp/ then It will delete the folder without any problems

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

The directory is owned by `root`, so you will need superuser privileges to delete it. Try,

```
sudo rm -rf Contents
```

which will ask you for your password before executing.  This will also give you temporary superuser privileges for all commands at the command prompt, so be careful with subsequent commands.

In fact, if you're not used to doing this, I suggest moving the directory to trash in the first instance, until you're sure you don't need anything in the bundle:

```
sudo mv Contents $HOME/.Trash/
```

Comment: We can't use sudo since this is done as part of an automatic-updates process

Comment: @kambi It's owned by root, so you can't delete it without either being root or being an admin and using sudo.